# Objects disconnecting when exported to Unity (FBX)

Tags: unity

I have a number of objects parented to one another in Blender.  I want to export them to Unity.  I've used an FBX export (many times, successfully, for single objects in the past) and ensured that **all the objects are selected**.  I have also confirmed that **all scales/rotations/locations** have been reset, for each object, and checked **all normals are pointing the correct way**.

I export to Unity, using FBX 7.4 binary, with "selected objects" checked.

The result is the picture - all that stuff is supposed to be connected.

There are numerous objects, but they're all selected, parented, etc.  What is causing them to explode like this, and how do I get a clean export?[image]

Thanks,

A

Comment: It seems to work ok if I switch to FBX 6.1 Ascii.  Doesn't work on 7.4.  Any idea why please?

Comment: Is ther a reason why you don't just place the blend files in the unity project and let unity export them in the backgrund how it likes? You can answer your own question here. You used some FBX version that seems to be not properly supportet by either Blender or Unity.

Comment: @J.Doe what? FBX is totally supported by Unity and has been for ages.  There's a million videos out there using FBX to import from Blender to Unity - and using 7.4.

Comment: Indeed i use it mostly happy nearyl every day. But conversion bewen file formats is a complex thing... and wierd conversion that has to be worked around happen even in things as easy as converting betwen differenc coordinate systhems. Maybe you can find a minimal example to pinpoint the wierd behavior. And then work around it or submit a bug somewere.